# Calculate cost of excess water consumed

Tags: calculation-puzzle

100 Liters of water is available equally in a month for consumption among 5 members @ 1 dollar per liter. If some members don't use their own available 20 liters, it can be used by the others at the same rate. (for example, if a member uses only 5 liter in that month, their remaining 5 liters can be used by others at $1). In a particular month, the usage was as follows:

A - 25 liters

B - 5 liters

C - 17 liters

D - 40 liters

E - 33 liters

The additional 20 liters was purchased at $10 per liter after the initial 100 liters were consumed disproportionately.
How do you calculate individual water cost of each member?

Comment: This seems more like a homework problem than a puzzle in the recreational sense.

Comment: Honestly, its a real life problem more than a home work. Numbers are toned down to understand the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the goal of the puzzle. Are we trying to distribute the costs in a certain way (such as a "fair" distribution that minimizes the differences between costs)?  Or can we suggest any way of distributing the water usage?  If so, that would result in many different answers.

Comment: This may be  a real life problem, but it is not a *puzzle*. It's just mechanical application of arithmetic, once you decide on a method of allocating the excess expense.  If your goal is to get us to give you that method, it's still not a *puzzle*, but now it's *too broad* and/or *primarily opinion based*.  Which close reason do you prefer? :)

Comment: Sounds like a dispute which should be in "Relationships", maybe with some more information on the personalities and existing agreements.  This isn't math nor a puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Everyone below 20 l pays the 1-dollar-per-l rate, so B pays 5 and C 17.  Their excess 18 l would then be distributed equally across the group, making 26 l available to A, D, and E at 1-dollar-per-l.  That means A pays 25, leaving 0.5 l for D and E.  I will presume that costs for halves would be distributed equally, so D pays 26.5 + 10*13.5 or 161.50, and E pays 26.5 + 10*6.5, or 91.50.